# Wrap jQuery plugins method in angularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

my project has several jQuery plugins and I need to wrap them inside angularJS. I did some research and I found how to make a custom directive for initialization. The question is: how can i handle methods called programmatically after initialization?

Comment: Please be a lot more specific and provide a [mcve]

Comment: You could try to wrap them in `$timeout` or call `$scope.$digest();` within those methods

Answer (score 0):

You should create a service between angularjs and Jquery, or even create a module that has the directive (initialization and events) and service (access to plugin api). In case you want to reuse it.